# async Function call to Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this

```
const Parent = () => {
    [modalOpen, setModal] = React.useState(false);

    return <Child
               open={modalOpen}
               closeModal={() => setModal(false)}
               functionFromParent={() => console.log('Logged')} />
}
```

and that

```
const Child = ({ functionFromStore, functionFromParent, closeModal }) => {
    async function foo() {
        try {
          await ...;
          functionFromStore();
          functionFromParent();
        } catch (error) {
          ....
        }
    }

    const bar = () => {
        foo();
        closeModal();
    }

    return <div
           style={{backgroundColor: 'hotpink', width: '10rem', height: '10rem' }}
           onClick={() => bar()}/>
}
```

component.

`<Parent />` decides if the `<Child />` (it is a *Modal*) shown or not. 
`<Child />` has three functions, `closeModal()` and `functionFromParent()`, coming from the `<Parent/ >`. And `functionFromStore()` coming from `redux` through `dispatchToProps()`. For the sake of simplicity I left all the `connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(...)` stuff out. But lets assume `<Child />` is directly connected to the `store`.

Clicking on the `<div />` in `<Child/>` executes `bar()`. That causes `<Child />` to `unmount`, because `closeModal()` in the `<Parent />` is called, closing the *modal*. However, `bar()` also calls `foo()`, being a `async` function.

When the `await` is resolved, the `functionFromStore()` is called, but not the `functionFromParent()`. I wonder why is that? Why is a function coming from the `store` called, even when the component (`<Child />`) is unmounted, but not the function coming from the parent?

Further, is there a way to call `functionFromParent()`, even when `<Child />` is unmounted? Somehow it works with `functionFromStore()`, is there a way to make it work with `functionFromParent()`?

Comment: `this.props` in function component?

Comment: @marzelin Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected it.

Comment: `is there a way to call functionFromParent(), even when <Child /> is unmounted?` Yes, no need to change anything I added an answer showing that your code already works. If it doesn't then it's because of something you didn't post in your question. Can you post code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that functionFromStore results in an error and because it's an asynchronous function it'll result in a rejected Promise. Chrome console can tell you if you have an uncaught promise or maybe log something in the catch?

Comment: @HMR Nope, there is no error. I also can move the `functionFromParent()` to the `error{ ... }` block, same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe but it's probably a [closure problem](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14010#issuecomment-468915443) as you're setting the state multiple times but have a stale state value in the closure of your handlers

You can solve it by passing a callback to the state setter: `setSomeState(currentState=>({...currentState,changes}))`, here is a full example:

```js
function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    showModal: true,
    showFoo: false,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {state.showModal ? (
        <Child
          open={state.showModal}
          closeModal={() =>
            setState(state => ({
              ...state,
              showModal: false,
            }))
          }
          functionFromParent={() =>
            setState(state => ({
              ...state,
              showFoo: true,
            }))
          }
        />
      ) : (
        'Child is gone '
      )}
      {state.showFoo ? <Foo /> : 'no foo'}
    </div>
  );
}
function Child({ functionFromParent, closeModal }) {
  function foo() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      functionFromParent();
    }, 1000);
  }
  const bar = () => {
    foo();
    closeModal();
  };
  return <button onClick={bar}>click me</button>;
}
function Foo() {
  return 'hi, I am Foo';
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You cannot reproduce because the `<Child />` does not 'really'  unmount in your code. Assume the `<Child />` is wrapped in a *modal*, https://material-ui.com/api/modal/. Then the `onClick={bar}` causes the *modal*  to unmount.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the condition you put there. Might it be because the `<Parent />` re-renders a couple of times while the `async` is called, causing `functionFormParent()` forget 'where it is coming from'? Not sure how to phrase this, but `<Parent />` re-renders a couple of times because there is stuff happening in the UI while the async call is done (Spinner, placeholder showing, ...). Might that be the reason, that `<Parent />` is created anew, and `functionFromParent()` in `<Child />` 'references'  the 'old' `<Parent />`, the one before the re-renders?

Comment: @Stophface what does `functionFromParent` really do? Changes the parent state? Something else?

Comment: It changes the state. `functionFromParent={foo => setState({ ...state, [foo]: true })}`

Comment: And thats the state `const [state, setState] = useState({
    modalOpen: false,
    [foo]: false,
    [bar]: false,
  });`

Comment: if `[foo]: true` another `Component` is rendered in `<Parent />`

Comment: @Stophface do you get any errors in the console regarding using `setState` on unmounted component?

Comment: Thats it... Damn. That cost some time. Thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: @Stophface No problem, should have guessed it had something to do with that as this causes a lot of unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

`functionFromParent` must have been called. There must be something else that causing the problem.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = React.useState(true);
  const childProps = {
    fnFromParent: () => {
      console.log("logging from fnFromParent");
    },
    unmount: () => {
      setShowChild(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I'm a Parent</p>
      { showChild &&
        <Child {...childProps} />
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ fnFromParent, unmount }) => {
  const delayed = () => {
    const p = new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 3000))
    p.then(() => fnFromParent());
  };
  const clickHandler = () => {
    delayed();
    unmount();
  };
  return <p onClick={clickHandler}>I'm a Child (click to remove me)</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but [we already established that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58573667/1641941), it could be that parent is unmounted and re mounted so state in Parent is reset.